# ConEmu error when trying to git commit a merge after conflict

Tags: git, cygwin, conemu, cmder

I'm using ConEmu version `180206 preview` to have some decent terminal on Windows with tabs support. Works very good on most part of the time.

But I'm having an error that occurs almost every time I commit changes after a merge conflict on Git. The error:

```
λ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...       0 [main] vim 7956 C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin\vim.exe: *** fatal error - cmalloc would have returned NULL
   1839 [main] vim 7956 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to vim.exe.stackdump
[feat/my-branch 7b0d482] Merge branch 'develop' into feat/my-branch
```

Even with the error, the commit is done correctly.

I don't know if the default git conflict message is a problem (I will investigate further in the next time that the error occur, maybe the single quotes cause this...), but follows this format:

```
Merge branch 'develop' into feat/my-branch
```

I visited some discussions about this problem and the only tip that I could extract from these discussions is reduce the buffer height (my actual value is 5000) but this solution not work for me.

So, what alternative I had to resolve this problem?

Comment: Not only buffer height matters. Decrease width and height of the window, decrease buffer height, open [RealConsole](http://conemu.github.io/en/RealConsole.html) and check result sizes. The bug is definitely somewhere in cygwin implementation of pty, it fails on large consoles. This should be reported to Cygwin team.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar error using windows dos console - and reducing the console buffer size to a more sane 25 lines and 120 chars wide sorted it out. It's not conemu alone.